# behavior of garbage collection for cluster-scope owner resources in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have two kubernetes clusters, both of them running kubernetes 1.26.3:

Cluster (A) is installed using kubespray on 5 bare metal machines, and cluster (B) which is installed using KinD on my local dev machine...

I'm seeing different behavior regarding garbage collection of owned resources between the two clusters, for example if I do the following:

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: parent
EOF
```

========

```
NS_UID=$(kubectl get namespace parent -o jsonpath="{.metadata.uid}")
```

========

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: child
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: Namespace
    name: parent
    uid: $NS_UID
EOF
```

If I delete the parent (`kubectl delete Namespace parent`), on cluster A I see that the child is also removed (which is the expected behavior since Namespaces are cluster-scoped)..
But on cluster B, only the parent is removed and the child is still in Active status...

I compared the admission plugins enabled between the two clusters but they are similar..

The documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/garbage-collection/#owners-dependents) has some notes but I'm using cluster-scope owner reference , so it should be ok

What could causer that difference in behavior and which one is correct?